# COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

Essentially, I am attempting to create a small tool in Java where I take the text from some kind of user input, think of an ordinary text box, and create a PDF file with it.

So far, I managed to scrape something really quickly with my barebones knowledge of PDFBox.

In my application, I am instantiating this class(the one shown below) in another one with GUI elements and if I input text, in let's say a text box, and running this `PDFLetter` script once - it works like a charm but running it a second time, it crashes and gives me this annoying error:

> COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps it's enclosing
>   PDDocument has been closed?

I do not really see any way that I could trigger this error in my code. I thought it had something to do with my rudimentary 'jump to next page' solution but it works in its current state, so I do not know what to believe anymore.

The way I am instantiating the class, in case you need to know, is like this:

```
PDFLetter.PDFLetterGenerate(textInput.getValue().toString());
```

Additionally, I thought it had to be some kind of a problem with garbage collection that triggered the problem but I no longer think that this is the case.

```
public class PDFLetter {
    private static final int PAGE_MARGIN = 80;

    static float TABLE_HEIGHT;  

    static Boolean newPage = false;

public static String text = // null;
        "Ding Dong ding dong Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et "
        + "Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac.";

static List<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();

PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
static PDPage main_page = new PDPage();
static PDPage new_page = new PDPage(); 

static File file = new File("C:/PDFTests/temp.pdf"); 

public void PDFLetterGenerate (String args) throws Exception {
    text = args;
    text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

    if(file.exists()) file.delete();
    file.createNewFile();
    //Creating PDF document object 
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();       
    document.addPage(main_page);  
    mainBody(document, main_page);      
    document.addPage(new_page);                          
    if(!newPage) document.removePage(new_page);

    document.save(file);
    document.close(); 
}

public static void mainBody(PDDocument doc, PDPage page) throws Exception { 
        final float width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth()-(2*PAGE_MARGIN);
        int fontSize = 11;
        float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;
        final float max = 256;
        PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);

        int lastSpace = -1;
        while (text.length() > 0){
            int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
            if (spaceIndex < 0) spaceIndex = text.length();
            String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
            float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;

            if (size > width){
                if (lastSpace < 0) lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
                textList.add(subString);
                text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
                lastSpace = -1;
            }

            else if (spaceIndex == text.length()){
                textList.add(text);
                text = "";
            }

            else{
                lastSpace = spaceIndex;
            }
        }

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(PAGE_MARGIN, TABLE_HEIGHT);


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        PDPageContentStream newStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, new_page, true, true);

        int nextPage_i = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<textList.size(); i++)//String line: textList){
            System.out.println("HEIGHT: "+ TABLE_HEIGHT);
            nextPage_i = i;
            String line = textList.get(i);
            float charSpacing = 0;

            if (line.length() > 1){         
                float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(line) / 1000;
                float free = width - size;
                if (free > 0){
                    charSpacing = free / (line.length() - 1);
                }
                TABLE_HEIGHT = TABLE_HEIGHT - 10;
            }

            contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(charSpacing); 
            contentStream.showText(line);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);

            if(TABLE_HEIGHT <= 280){  
                contentStream.endText();  
                contentStream.close(); 
                newPage = true;
                break; 
            } 
        } 

        if(!newPage){
            contentStream.endText();  
            contentStream.close(); 
        }

        else if (newPage){          
            float NEW_HEIGHT = 600;             
            newStream.beginText();
            newStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
            newStream.newLineAtOffset(PAGE_MARGIN, NEW_HEIGHT);

            for (int j=nextPage_i; j<textList.size(); j++)//String line: textList){
                System.out.println("HEIGHT: "+ NEW_HEIGHT);
                nextPage_i = j;
                String line = textList.get(j);
                float charSpacing = 0;

                if (line.length() > 1){         
                    float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(line) / 1000;
                    float free = width - size;
                    if (free > 0)
                    {
                        charSpacing = free / (line.length() - 1);
                    }
                    NEW_HEIGHT = NEW_HEIGHT - 10; 
                }
                newStream.setCharacterSpacing(charSpacing); 
                newStream.showText(line);
                newStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
            }
            newStream.endText();  
            newStream.close();
        }
        lastSpace = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull the `PDPage` instantiations into `PDFLetterGenerate`:

```
public void PDFLetterGenerate (String args) throws Exception {
    PDPage main_page = new PDPage();
    PDPage new_page = new PDPage(); 

    text = args;
    text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

    if(file.exists()) file.delete();
    file.createNewFile();
    //Creating PDF document object 
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();       
    document.addPage(main_page);  
    mainBody(document, main_page);      
    document.addPage(new_page);                          
    if(!newPage) document.removePage(new_page);

    document.save(file);
    document.close(); 
}
```

In your code the pages are instantiated once and the underlying streams are closed after the first run of `PDFLetterGenerate` when the local `PDDocument document` is closed after having the pages added to it.

Furthermore, also make `new_page` an argument of `mainBody` instead of counting on a static variable to hold it.

There are a number of other issues in your code, but the changes above should get you started.

Comment: Bless your heart, it is a silly issue but sometimes I guess everyone gets stumped like that.